# PHP Regex to Change New Line Characters between Specific Tags

Tags: php, regex

How can I change new line characters to <br> which are only between <p> and </p> tags...?

```
$text = preg_replace( '#<P>(.*?)\r\n(.*?)</P>#s', '<P>$1<BR>$2</P>', $text );
```

This made only the first new line character to be <br>.

Comment: Please update your question with sample of your string. You may also try using `str_replace()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

This has [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) written all over it...

I will provide you with a regular expression (as this is what you're asking for) but I would urge you to take a look at the post I've linked above. **Regex is not the best tool for this job.**

---

### Code

#### Version 1

If you *really* want a regex solution for this, you can use the following:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yA2WsW/4)

```
(?:<p>|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!</p>).)*?\K\v(?=[\s\S]*?</p>)
```

#### Version 2

Assuming you also want to catch `<p x>` where `x` represents some arbitrary number of attributes, you can use the following regex:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yA2WsW/3)

```
(?:<p.*?>|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!</p>).)*?\K\v(?=[\s\S]*?</p>)
```

This regex matches `<p.*?>` instead of simply `<p>`.

---

### Results

#### Input

```
<p>something 

here</p>

<p>
Something else
here
</p>
```

#### Output

```
<p>something <br/><br/>here</p>

<p><br/>Something else<br/>here<br/></p>
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:<p>|\G(?!\A))` Match either of the following

  - `<p>` Matches `<p>` literally
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match, negating (using a negative lookahead) the start of the string for the first match (thus, this asserts position at the end of the previous match).
- `(?:(?!</p>).)*?` Match the following any number of times, but as few as possible

  - `(?!</p>).` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not `<p>` literally. Assuming the negative lookahead doesn't match, match any character (except newline character since the `s` modifier is not used).
  - `\K` Reset the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.
  - `\v` Match any vertical whitespace character
  - `(?=[\s\S]*?</p>)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches the following

    - `[\s\S]*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
    - `</p>` Match `</p>` literally

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer...! : )

Comment: You’re very welcome! Maybe you’d consider marking your question as “answered” then? :)

Answer (score 0):

An example with a parser **and** a regular expression: this sets up the `DOM` first, queries it for `p` tags and then inserts the modified text back again.

```
<?php

$html = <<<DATA
<div>
    <p class="someclass">Some very import
    information here
    and here as well
    </p>
</div>
DATA;

# set up the DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

# set up the xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

# regex 
$regex = '~\R\s*~';

foreach ($xpath->query("//p") as $line) {
    $newnode = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $newnode->appendXML(preg_replace($regex, "<br />", $line->textContent));
    $line->nodeValue = '';
    $line->appendChild($newnode);

}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

---

This produces

```
<div>
    <p class="someclass">Some very import<br>information here<br>and here as well<br></p>
</div>
```

---

Note: this will fail for sth. like:

```
<div>
    <p class="someclass">Some very import
    information here <img src="some-picture.png">
    and here as well
    </p>
</div>
```